# Can't start Kafka/Zookeeper Service on Centos 7/Centos 8

Tags: apache-kafka, centos, centos7, centos8

Paths are correct, I don't know why I can't start kafka service, all lines, log files, etc and do not say what the Issue is... :/

I'm trying to install kafka on my Centos 7/8 and there is no Issue description I can figure out.

**zookeeper.service** file:

```
[Unit] 
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target 
After=network.target remote-fs.target 

[Service] 
Type=simpleUser=kafka 

ExecStart=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties 
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.shRestart=on-abnormal 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**kafka.service** file:

```
[Unit] 
Requires=zookeeper.service 
After=zookeeper.service 

[Service] 
Type=simple 
User=kafka 
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/server.properties > /home/kafka/kafka/kafka.log 2>&1'
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-server-stop.shRestart=on-abnormal 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: I was trying to solve kafka Issue when I sould check zookeeper service first. Please check the workaround below.

Comment: can you telnet to the zookeeper server?

Comment: FWIW, you can install them as services via the instructions here: https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/installing_cp/rhel-centos.html#systemd-rhel-centos-install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found the solution and I'm posting it because I saw a lot of questions regarding this Issue hoping I can also help them.

So, please check out the new command line **ExecStart**:

**zookeeper.service** file:

```
[Unit] 
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target 
After=network.target remote-fs.target 

[Service] 
Type=simpleUser=kafka 

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties'
ExecStop=/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

On **Centos** (7/8/ X Version) it needs to specify the batch like this (using **/bin/sh -c ''**):

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/home/kafka/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /home/kafka/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties'
```

[image: zookeeper working as expected]

After this, you can run the kafka service! :)

Answer (score 1):

From [Kafka docs Quickstart](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_startserver)

> Kafka uses ZooKeeper so you need to first start a ZooKeeper server if
>   you don't already have one. You can use the convenience script
>   packaged with kafka to get a quick-and-dirty single-node ZooKeeper
>   instance.

Start zookeeper server with default settings

```
$ bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
```

Start Kakfa server with default settings

```
$ bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

If you had already done this step and still getting this error, Kafka server is unable to reach zookeeper service. Please check zookeeper server is running and listening on port mentioned (clientPort, default port: 2181) in zookeeper.properties file using anyone of the following commands - *netstat*, *lsof*, and *telnet*